# How to turn if, else if logic into a ternary operator?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I was just wondering if this was possible because i started using ternary operators to reduce lines of code and i am loving it.

```
if (x==y)
{
    z += x;
} else if (x==z)
{
    z += y;
} else {
   z += 1;
}
```

i can do this now if there is only one if statement like this:

```
z = x == y ? z += x : z += 1;
```

Comment: "i started using ternary operators to reduce lines of code and i am loving it" Uh oh.

Comment: Well if there is only a single instruction you can remove braces. And it's more readable than ternary. Imo

Comment: @BoltClock Instead of just saying that, can you explain why that is bad?  I am always willing to listen.

Comment: You need to be careful with using the ternary operator. Don't just use it because it's cool-looking or just to reduce lines of code. Like Maresh said, if you really want to reduce lines of code you can start by removing those braces. You don't need to squeeze everything into a single line. The use case you've given here is one where you should really strive not to use it, even though you theoretically can.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It would be like this:

```
z =
  x == y ? z + x :
  x == z ? z + y :
  z + 1;
```

If you use `z += x` as an operand it will end up doing `z = (z += x)`. While it works in this special case, as the result of the expression `z += x` is the final value of `z`, it may not work in other cases.

Howver, as all operations have the `z +=` in common, you can do like this:

```
z +=
  x == y ? x :
  x == z ? y :
  1;
```

Use with care, though. The code is often more readable and maintainable the simpler it is, and nested conditional operations are not very readable. Also, use this only when you have an *expression* as the result of the conditional operation, it's not a drop-in replacement for the `if` statement.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
z += x == y ? x : x == z ? y : 1;
```

But honestly, that's not really more readable than what you had before. You can make it slightly clearer by adding parentheses:

```
z += x == y ? x : (x == z ? y : 1);
```

But generally I'd stay away from nested conditional operators unless when golfing.

Comment: With some judicious newlines, I think this could be *more* readable than the original.

Comment: Michael: Agreed; added a note for that. recursive: I just tried formatting it over multiple lines but failed in making it any more comprehensible. Maybe I just suck. But maybe complex conditional operators are hard to format for readability.

Comment: @Joey:  Guffa has got the same idea that I did.  To me, his solution seems quite readable.

Answer (score 5):

Four lines of code, and the most readable, IMO. No need for a ternary operator here:

```
if (x == y || x == z)
    z += y;
else 
   z++;
```

If I had to write it using ternary, I would do:

```
z += (x == y || x == z) ? y : 1;
```

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: What's the difference?

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: It executes in exactly the same way though. No point deciding whether to add `x` or `y` if both are going to be the same, and if they're not then you're adding `y` *anyway*.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko So far as my testing goes, it is.

Comment: Yes, it's actually the same as the original, as when x == y, z += x is the same as z += y. However, I'm pretty sure that it's just an example, and the use of the conditonal operator is the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

you should do this by using parentheses like this:

```
(x==y)?(z+=x):((x==z)?(z+=y):(z+=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple to continue with ternary operator rather than if else if condition, just need to continue the same even after ":". below is the sample.

```
var result = a ? x : b ? y : z;
```

[Reference example](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2017/04/if-else-if-condition-using-operator-in-csharp.html)

Answer (score 0):

To turn the `z` calculation into one line, I would do something like this:

```
public int GetZBasedOnXY(int z, int x, int y)
{
    // Chose this solution, but any can go in here and work.
    if (x == y || x == z)
        return z + y;
    else 
        return z + 1;
}
```

Then:

```
z = GetZBasedOnXY(z, x, y);
```

More readable, and if the naming is good and the method has unit test coverage, even better.

Comment: That's not ternary operation for if else.

Comment: @dicemaster Yes I'm aware. I was offering a different way to compress a conditional into a single line on use. Plenty of other answers showing the ternary (and how horrendous it ends up looking).