# How to write shorthand if-statement with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, if-statement

For example i want to write:

```
txt1.Text=="A" || txt2.Text="A" ? return true : return false
```

I know how to work with one condition but with two i don't know.

The txt2.Text="A" instead of txt2.Text=="A" it's not what i meant.

My question was how do i add a condition to this specific if.
Yes, i know how to use in if.

the regular way to use in the other if is:

txt1.Text=="A"? return true: return false

and i want to improve that.

The code that i have written doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: return (condition) ? true : false

Comment: You answered you own question. That's how to write it

Comment: condition ? true : false is repetitive and redundant and repetitive and redundant.

Comment: Your code is probably not working because `txt2.Text="A"` does not use the `==` operator.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436076/how-to-turn-if-else-if-logic-into-a-ternary-operator

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Don't forget superfluous, repetitive, and superfluous.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for

```
return txt1.Text == "A" || txt2.Text == "A";
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
if(txt1.Text == "A" || txt2.Text == "A") //checks if txt1 is A OR txt2 is A
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
```

Comment: "How to write 8 lines where one is perfectly sufficient"

Comment: For a learner's point of view, when TEACHING someone, you do it in the easiest-to-view method, then build up your understanding via showing other methods. People can't just be thrown into the deep end and expected to swim.