# Expand a ternary statement or switch to if-else

Tags: javascript

I have the following which works fine with two conditions:

```
var value = this.value === "foo" ? function(d) {
    return d.foo;
} : function(d) {
    return d.bar;
};
```

What am I doing wrong when I try to expand the above to the following using `if-else`?

```
var value = 
if (this.value === "foo") {
        function(d) {
            return d.foo;
        };
    } else
if (this.value === "bar") {
    function(d) {
        return d.bar;
    };
} else {
    function(d) {
        return d.qux;
    };
}
```

I'm happy to stick with operators or switching to if-else : whatever is more readable for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn if, else if logic into a ternary operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436076/how-to-turn-if-else-if-logic-into-a-ternary-operator)

Comment: JS simply doesn't support that style of assignment

Comment: Because that isn't how JavaScript works. An `if` statement isn't the same as a ternary.

You might want to consider putting the functions into an object instead--but it may also be you're missing an abstraction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if` cannot be used on the right-hand side of an assignment statement (which is part of why we have the conditional operator).

Instead, assign in each branch:

```
var value;
if (this.value === "foo") {
    value = function(d) {
        return d.foo;
    };
} else if (this.value === "bar") {
    value = function(d) {
        return d.bar;
    };
} else {
    value = function(d) {
        return d.qux;
    };
}
```

---

Although note that that *particular* code can be simplified:

```
var key = this.value == "foo" || this.value == "bar" ? this.value : "qux";
var value = function(d) {
    return d[key];
};
```

Comment: thanks you for help with this - in particular this `return d[key];` helps me with another aspect of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a conditional block statement to assign a value to a variable. You can use the ternary operator you were using in the first example and double it:

```
var value = (this.value === "foo") ? function(d) {
    return d.foo;
} : (this.value === "bar") ? function(d) {
    return d.bar;
} : function(d) {
    return d.qux;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The first once works because the ternary operator by default returns the result of either first or second expression based on the condition

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

while the if-else block only check for the condition and do not return anything by default and thats why can not be on the right side of any assignment.

Answer (score 1):

There's another approach.  It doesn't quite fit these requirements, but I do assume that these requirements aren't your precise ones (or do you have actual needs for 'foo', 'bar', and 'quz' :-) ? )

You can capture the value in a wrapping function:

```
function createValueFunc(val) {
    return function(d) {
        return d[val];
    };
}

value = createValueFunc(this.value);
```

This does not handle your `else` case, so it may be useless to you.  But if it's useful, you can simplify it in ES6 to:

```
createValueFunc = (name) => (obj) => obj[name];
```

You'll find such a function in many utility libraries.  Underscore calls it [`property`](http://underscorejs.org/#property).  Ramda calls it [`prop`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#prop).  Sometimes I've seen it called `get` as well.